# allocated but not initialized

Tags: c++, allocation

I have met aN allocated but not initialized issue.

here is part of the code:

```
void test2(vector<string> names, int num) // just for test
{
    const char  **tmp = new const char *[num]; // issue happends here.
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i ++)
        tmp[i] = names[i].c_str(); // is it not inialization???
    //call another function using tmp
    delete []tmp; 
}
```

well in the line 3 of the code, i got an issue:  Assigning: "tmp" = "new char const *[num]", which is allocated but not initialized.

i believe i got confused with the 2-d arrays allocations and initialization. I think that the tmp is the const char * array, and I just want to convert the vertor to const char **;

then in the code, is it right to use the new and delete here?

i know that if the 2d array is int**, then if I want to assign value to it, i need to new int*[num], then do a for loop to new int[]; but how about my case here?

can someone help me with this piece of code?

Comment: constants are constant.

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Is the compiler complaining? If so, post the message. Is the code not doing what you expect it to do? Show how you're exercising the code, describe what you expect it to do, and what it's actually doing.

Comment: I suspect the code in the question isn't really the same as the code you're having trouble with.

Comment: What program gave you that message? [I can't reproduce it easily](http://ideone.com/dAEOKU)

Comment: @IsmetAlkan - what's your point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use const in this situation because you're allocating data post-initialization.

Comment: i think i'd better use vector<const char *>;

Comment: const char  **tmp = new const char *[num];
here is just a allocation, and you must initialize as long as you allocate the memory.

and in the for loop, it is not initialization, but assignment.

so in this case, we'd better use vector<const char *> instead of const char**